# When does Lusztig's canonical basis have non-positive structure coefficients?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, canonical-bases

I've heard asserted in talks quite a few times that Lusztig's canonical basis for irreducible representations is known to not always have positive structure coefficents for the action of $E_i$ and $F_i$.  There are good geometric reasons the coefficents have to be positive in simply-laced situations, but no such arguments can work for non-simply laced examples.  However, this is quite a bit weaker than knowing the result is false.

> Does anyone have a good example or reference for a situation where this positivity fails?

Comment: I do not know any reference in the literature nor who found a counter-example at the first time.

But, here in Kyoto, everybody believes there are counter-examples. Don't ask me the detail.

Comment: In the related world of Hecke algebras with unequal parameters the "Kazhdan-Lusztig" basis can have structure constants that aren't nonnegative, which happens already for B_2 where you have parameters $q$ and $q^2$. I think this was noticed by Lusztig in the early 80s. (And I'd be stunned if he didn't have a similar example in the case of quantum groups, but I never asked him).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hi,

The following formulas are examples of non-positive structure coefficients
for non-symmetric cases which are easily verified by the algorithm presented
in Leclerc's paper "Dual Canonical Bases, Quantum Shuffles, and q-characters" 
or quagroup package in GAP4.

Professor Masaki Kashiwara told me that he has known such non-positive 
structure coefficient for $G_2$ since Shigenori Yamane found it in 1994
as treated in his master thesis at Osaka University (written in Japanese).
You can see similar negative coefficients in at least case $A_{2n}^{(2)}, D_{n+1}^{(2)}$.
Anyway, conjecture 52 in Leclerc's paper is false 
(I already told Professor Leclerc about it).

Shunsuke Tsuchioka

Notation: $G(i_1,\cdots,i_n)$ stands for the canonical basis element
corresponds to a crystal element 
$b(i_1,\cdots,i_n)=\tilde{f}_{i_n}b(i_1,\cdots,i_{n-1})=\cdots$.

$G_2$ (1 is the short root) : 
$f_2 G(121112211)
= G(1211122211)
  + [2]G(1111222211)
  + G(2111112221)$

$  + [2]G(1211112221)
  + G(1111122221)
  - G(1112211122)
  + [2]G(1122111122)$

$C_3$ (1,2 are short roots) :
$f_3 G(23122312)
= [2]G(222333121)
  + [2]G(312222331)
  + [2]G(231222331)$

$  + [2]G(122223331)
  + G(231223312)
  + [2]G(122233312)
  - G(223112233)
  + [2]G(231122233)$

$B_4$ (1,2,3 are long roots) :
$f_1G(4342341234)
= [2]G(43344423211)
  + [2]G(43423443211)
  - G(44233443211)$

$  + [2]G(43423344211)
  + [2]G(43423442311)
  + [2]G(34234442311)$

$  + [2]G(43422334411)
  + G(43423412341)$

Answer (score 3):

Ben,

I have heard the same thing, but I have never seen an example. After thinking about it a bit, I came up with the following 'heuristic' reason why the structure constants should be positive for half the Chevalley generators.

Assume that it is know that simple modules for affine quiver Hecke algebras have characters given by the dual canonical basis of $U_q({n})$ (many people (not including Nakajima) expected to be true, but in light of Tsuchioka's answer shouldn't!). References for what follows are Leclerc's paper ["Dual Canonical Bases, Quantum Shuffles, and $q$-characters"](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=leclerc&s5=&s6=&s7=shuffle&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=1&mx-pid=2045836) (**EDIT** (BW) This is also on the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0209133)) as well as the paper of [Kleshchev and Ram](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1984), and [my paper with Melvin and Mondragon](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2067).

We denote the canonical and dual canonical bases $b_g$ and $b_g^*$, respectively, where $g$ runs over an appropriate index set. These bases are related by the Kashiwara form $(\cdot,\cdot)_K:U_A(n)\times U_A^*(n)\to A$ via

$$
(b_g,b_h^*)_K=\delta_{gh}
$$

(above, $A=\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]$ as usual). This form is defined so that $(1,1)_K=1$ and $(f_iu,v)_K=(u,f_i'v)_K$ and $f_i'$ is Kashiwara's $q$-derivation.

Now, on the level of modules, the $q$-derivation $f_i'$ corresponds to $i$-restriction. As we have assumed $b^*_g$ is the character of a simple module, we have the $f_i'\mathcal{b}^*_g$ is the character of some module, and hence a nonnegative linear combination of dual canonical basis vectors. So now we calculate
\begin{align*}
f_i\mathcal{b}_g=\sum_h(f_ib_g,b^*_h)_Kb_h
=\sum_h(b_g,f_i'b^*_h)_Kb_h.
\end{align*}
But, as we have explained, $(b_g,f_i'b^*_h)$ is nonnegative.

As I said above, this argument only works for half the generators. I haven't internalized the results of your recent paper, so I'm not sure if you've defined the biadjoint functor $e_i$ or not. If you have, then probably there should be some more information to be teased out of this line of reasoning.

Comment: Could you exclude Nakajima from `everyone' in the 6th line, please ?

Comment: I got it for you.

Comment: David- You, of course, sussed out my reason for asking the question in the first place; I've seen Aaron Lauda assert in talks that outside symmetric type the basis coming from categorifications can't be Lusztig's because it has positive structure coefficients and Lusztig's doesn't.  In symmetric type, it's known that you get the right thing for the enveloping algebra by Vasserot and Varagnolo's paper (arXiv:0901.3992).  For reducing to cyclotomic quotients, you might have to use the stuff in my papers (which does include biadjointness of the E_i and F_i functors).

Comment: I always feel like one shouldn't need a result as strong as biadjointness, but this feeling keeps being wrong.  

Comment: Harry - Thank you. After Tsuchioka's answer, it is probably better to change `everyone' to `nobody'.

Comment: Okay, I changed it. 

Comment: In the last spring Kashiwara gave a talk on KLR algebras and asked us (in particular, to Tsuchioka) what is the base given by simple modules for non-symmetric cases. My comments above were vague, as it was not clear that I can make public Kashiwara's question. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. I find this whole discussion very interesting. The Lyndon basis theory works really well for these algebras. It seems we have two different canonically defined bases coming from the same dual PBW basis. How are they related? Is there some way to twist the isomorphism in Kashiwara's definition of the global basis to make them coincide? Or is the relation more complicated?

Comment: I do not know any results on this problem. By the way, could you explain how Leclerc (and you) concludes his base $\{ b_g\}$ coincides with the canonical base ? Easy to show that they coincide up to sign. But how does he remove the sign ambiguity ? The only way I know is to use Saito's result (Publ. RIMS, 1994). I would like to know if there are other methods.

Comment: This is a very interesting point and maybe there is an issue? Leclerc constructs his basis $\{b_g\}$ using Lusztig's construction (so in some sense it is the canonical base by definition). First, he defines a PBW basis $\{E_g\}$ using an action of the braid group (there is more than one choice of action, but I don't know how much it matters). Then he obtains a unique bar invariant $b_g=E_g + \cdots$. The $E_g$ that Leclerc constructs are very natural in the sense that they have a well defined highest order term, and the coefficient of the leading terms are positive.

Comment: There is NO issue. Lusztig proved that the base $\{ b_g \}$ coincides with the base given by perverse sheaves (and hence is the canonical base) for type $ADE$. And later Saito proved the same result in general. This result is true for any choice of a reduced expression of the longest element of the Weyl group. Since Saito's proof use the whole of Kashiwara's theory, I am looking for a simpler proof. 

Comment: I thought you were suggesting that the $\{b_g\}$ basis might only coincide with the canonical basis up to sign, though as I understand you now, this is not the case. I do not know of any alternative to Saito's result.